# Graph API and FQL return only 58 results from likes table for external url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I use the following query to get the likes of an external url:

```
<?php

require_once('facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'xxxxxxx',
   'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));

$get =  array(
          'access_token' => 'xxxx'
          );

$res = $facebook->api('xxxxxx/likes', 'GET', $get);
print_r($res);

?>
```

For some reason the above query return only 58 user ids and stops. Tried the following:

1. Using Limit or Offset
2. Only 1 `after` cursor is returned which still show a total of 58
3. Tried using app access_token or user access_token with read_stream
4. Tried using different apps and still the same
5. Tried using different urls and the same results returned or even less
6. Tried the FQL equivalent and still the same

It worked only for the first time and I got all the ids but after that tried again with the same url and different ones and it never works again.

BTW it works very well with internal facebook posts or pages with a limit of 1000 ids per page but you can use pagination to get all the ids. For external only those 58 uids.

Is this a limitation or a bug or what?

Comment: In your example, you're calling 'xxxxx/likes' - what is 'xxxxx'? a page ID? a post ID? a share ID?

Comment: it's the object ID because it's an external URL...I created a bug on facebook and they told me that it's "by design" for privacy reasons

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a limitation, should read this page maybe will help you.

"You might notice that the number of results returned is not always equal to the “limit” specified. This is expected behavior. Query parameters are applied on our end before checking to see if the results returned are visible to the viewer. Because of this, it is possible that you might get fewer results than expected."

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

I have problems just with the 1000 likes limitation on fql. I never met this problem for post that had <1000 likes.